# Update text content with minified.js

Tags: javascript, minifiedjs

What is the right way to update text of **a** element with [minifiedjs](http://minifiedjs.com/)?

E.g.

```
<a class="myRef">Old text</a>
```

I have tried logical:

```
$('.myRef').text('New text');
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://minifiedjs.com/docs/howto.html#html_text

```
$('.myRef').fill("My new text");
```

I get it right from documentation.

Comment: Thats simple). Thx, looked only at the API, will go through this how to now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`fill` method](http://minifiedjs.com/api/fill.html) to replace the existing text value.

```
$('.myRef').fill("New Text Value");
```

or you can use the [`add` method](http://minifiedjs.com/api/add.html) to append text to the existing text.

```
$('.myRef').add("Append Text");
```

(The [`text` method](http://minifiedjs.com/api/text.html) returns the concatenated text content of all nodes in the list.)

[This list](http://minifiedjs.com/docs/howto.html) of How To's is helpful for learning how to use minifiedjs.